# Please make "unwatch tag" and "ignore tag" less prominent

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

When I open a [watched tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching), I am mostly interested in seeing the tagged questions, not in unwatching or ignoring that tag. I presume most users think alike.

Yet recent design change made those two buttons most prominent (due to size and placement):

[image: Unwatch Ignore buttons on StackOverflow]

Comment: Yech. And I don't even know what it means..

Comment: @TaW I edited the question to include a link to the announcement of Tag watching. tl;dr - it is the replacement of favorite tags.

Comment: Thanks. What a mess. I count 6 different button styles on the questions page..

Comment: So much wasted screen space...

Comment: Instead of seeing ~4 questions for currently observed tag, now I can see only 2 (without scrolling, which I don't want to do because notifications are at top bar which is at top and I want it to stay there, not to slide while scrolling). Wasn't tag description previously in column containing hot/featured posts? Can someone share image showing old look (possibly vs new look so we could compare it)?

Comment: Adding more to the point by @Pshemo. I have two modes of using SO; I want an answer to a question I have (in which case I just see the question content and that is generally fine when I load a specific question) or I want to browse questions I might be able to answer. In the latter case, questions under a tag are losing more and more space to, for this use-case, clutter. 2 questions on a laptop screen and the rest just fluff.

Comment: As with all new UI elements, users should have the ability to opt out. Then, if everybody opts out, you know you made a bad design decision.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment because I realized it was about the watched/ignored tag boxes in the sidebar and not the unwatch/ignore buttons that this question is about. Although my sentiments still stand.

Comment: While we're making things less prominent, I also think the box-shadow around the restyled widgets on the sidebar is a bit much. Note how in contrast, the community bulletin and the job ads above and below on the sidebar _don't_ have a box shadow. **Edit** I just unchecked the `box-shadow` property from `.s-sidebarwidget` in the developer tools and the sidebar looks _much_ cleaner that way.

Comment: It took me a while to notice the subtle `border-radius` as well, but unchecking that on `.s-sidebarwidget` also makes the new widgets on the sidebar more uniform with the existing elements.

Comment: There is the possibility to edit your watched tags on the right  - why duplicate it?

Comment: It's temporary: the "Python Jobs" link will soon be made the most prominent item on the page. :)

Comment: Same with the popover. I really don't use these features.

Comment: I totally agree with changing this. A simple collapsible panel would do the job - as long as you remember my preference :-) Or maybe auto hide it for users over a certain reputation?

Comment: @Cœur I am personally looking forward to "Python customized SO merch".

Comment: With AdBlock Plus this whole issue is moot

Comment: If you are following a tag, I suspect you know what it is about and don't need the description.  However, I want to say that every time I see those buttons, possibly because they are so huge, I feel I'm supposed to click something, but then I actually really worry about accidentally unfollowing.

Comment: why it is not reverted yet ?

Comment: *"With AdBlock Plus this whole issue is moot"* Maybe, but having to make all these customizations to work around new "features" is getting a little ridiculous (1. over-wide left menu, 2. over large "unwatch" tag, 3. lack of contrast, etc...)

Comment: Am I the only one who find it confusing that the disable option looks like it is "active"? The text of this button should not change when active. Otherwise one cold think that "Unwatch tag" is active.

Answer (score 70):

I hardly post on Meta, but SO front page has been changing quite a bit too many times lately, with no improvement to make up for the inconvenience!
I'd go one step further than the OP's proposal, and remove the entire tag description block. We don't need this on every single page, forever! Who really needs a tag description permanently cluttering the space?

If we made the `[Python]` clickable or hoverable, that'll amply do.
The watch/unwatch/ignore/nore is already on the right side bar, it is not necessary there.
Surely, there must be other, & better ways to induce people's goodwill to edit and improve tag definitions.

[image]

Comment: Right-side bar does not provide add/remove function for the current tag (We can't expect a user to type in a name of the currently opened page)

Comment: LOL you are rearranging the Titanic deck chairs! Why would we need that? type it in the favorite tags (now un-necessarily renamed "watched tags"). Change for the sake of change?

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I [reposted this on Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312217/388562)

Comment: Great @AndréKool - anything to stop the zealots intent on keeping their jobs in perpetuity from randomly changing stuff that works! Gaining new comers is fine, but not at the expense of existing users.

Comment: While we're complaining, I'd like the default to the tag **not** to be watched. I've always disliked the feature and never found it useful, but until now, there was nothing that could be done about it.

Comment: It's a bit hard to hover on a touch tablet, it would need a little "down arrow" thing as well.

Comment: There is an `info` button between the number of questions and Newest button... how about you click on that instead @Anders? The we can remove the whole oversized "Questions tagged [whatever]", the tags appear in the search box smack above it anyway.

Comment: I upvoted but I disagree that the buttons are unnecessary. What if you have a whole bunch of tags. I think I would rather just have a convenient link to click while I'm on the tag page. Maybe just make the "unwatch" and "ignore" buttons in the same style as those other links (i.e. "Learn More", "Improve Tag Info", etc.)

Comment: +1 If I searched for _[python]_, I'm quite likely to know what Python is already.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Funny, I don't think I've seen that before, when the design changed I ignored the page header. I agree that the thing needs to be hidden. If the info button stays then maybe it should not have the same design as the filter/sort buttons.

Comment: If only you'd used freehand red circles, this would have a thousand upvotes.

Answer (score 16):

Come on people, frequently accessed important functionality definitely deserves prominent exposure in the GUI, that's like good UX 101.

It is beyond perfectly clear that people frequently unwatch and ignore tags they have previously subscribed to. I myself do it all the time. 5-6 times a day at least.

Which is why I feel like this new eye sore is perfectly justified. Losing it is not desirable, as it will severely impede the proficiency at which I use the site.

---

OK, now to get constructive:

- first, it is abundantly clear that both the buttons and the text info are redundant if the "tag view" displays a tag a user has subscribed to. A simple check that can be made so a cleaner tag view can be presented for those tags that are frequently viewed by a particular user. A user is implied to have interest and know about the tags he is subscribed to, so there is no need to pollute the GUI with those buttons and the tag info.
- second, for end users it is still possible to filter out that GUI element entirely, the watched and ignored tags are still trivial to manage from the right side bar, and the info button is still right there, rendering a much more appealing version:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the sarcasm... -1 because someone might take it seriously...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar what sarcasm? I am being serial!

Comment: if you're a JavaScript developer, you're probably serious. Who cares about last weeks hot new framework anyway ;) So unwatch and ignore it.

Comment: @jps it will also be beneficial to have a third button for figuratively spitting on its grave too, with disgust.

Comment: *alarm noise* https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369938/now-that-we-can-detect-snark-what-are-we-planning-to-do-with-it

Comment: To those poor souls capable of getting "offended" by irony - I feel offended that you are offended by irony. Stop being so damn offensive!!! Respect my right of literary expression!!!