# Stop telling me to unwatch things!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The recent redesign has made toggling tag watching the most prominent UI element on the screen. It's annoying when it shows up on mouseover, since these are the actions I want to take literally never:

[image]

But it's even more obnoxious when it comes to search. I very frequently search for specific users' answers to either retrieve information or as possible dupe targets. And when I do, I'm greeted with this:

[image]

Not only do I, again, literally never want to toggle my watch settings at this time, I certainly don't need a reminder of it twice.

Can we please, please, get rid of all of this?

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same. It is really annoying and unwelcoming especially for tag bound users.

Comment: yes, there should be a way to *unwatch* all these things!

Comment: I think this was discussed somewhere on MSE. I agree. The most prominent button is now unwatch, and I am not sure if unwatching is something that wants to be encouraged.

Comment: If only the tag wiki, also known as "Learn more..." was the most prominent part of that section. It is certainly the most relevant option to click on.

Comment: You're reporting 2 things that each have their own duplicate. [Please make “unwatch tag” and “ignore tag” less prominent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370561/7795130) and [Double tag information and double search bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371566/7795130).

Comment: Is it actually possible to "unwatch" something? You could not watch it, I guess, but does that mean you're unwatching it?

Comment: Agreed.  And the old mouseover had a modest direct link to "Top users", which IMO was much more useful than the oversized "Unwatch Tag" and "Ignore Tag" buttons.

Comment: [You cannot unsee.](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/001/248/cannotbeunseen.jpg)

Comment: @kjhughes: The old mouseover also had links to the tag wiki.  Several of my answers have `See the [tag:x86] tag wiki for more links`.  Later I tended to just link [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) like a regular link in case people didn't figure out the mouseover, but this change broke my old answers that assumed the tag mouseover would give you a link to the tag wiki.

Comment: @m69: Good question; I think that "to unwatch" means "to stop watching" rather than "to not watch".