# Autoflag bad closed questions as a breach of the Code of Conduct

Tags: feature-request, welcoming, code-of-conduct

The new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) applies to the askers of questions, not only answerers and curators:

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. [Follow our guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers.

A question that does not follow our guidelines on how to ask a question, or does not respect that the community consists of volunteers, fails to meet the expectations of the Code of Conduct.

Curators who [become frustrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367016/curation-and-cynicism-or-why-stack-overflow-sometimes-doesnt-seem-welcoming) and are a [bit snarky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369938/now-that-we-can-detect-snark-what-are-we-planning-to-do-with-it) in a comment are judged as not welcoming, and can have their comment easily flagged "for moderator attention" as an "unfriendly or unkind" violation of the Code of Conduct. This quickly leads to deletion of the comment. The Code of Conduct notes that this will be accompanied by a warning and "repetitive misconduct" will result in account suspension.

Of course, there should be no double standards for moderator intervention and deletion of contributions when there are violations of the Code of Conduct. Therefore it should be easy to flag *questions* as violations, and bad questions should be deleted just as rapidly as bad comments.

Some of the standard close reasons for questions (in whole or in part) indicate failure to meet expectations of the Code of Conduct by a question asker:

- *Unclear what you're asking*: does not "make it as easy as possible for others to help"
- *Too broad*: for gimme-teh-codez requirements dumps and zero-effort homework questions does not respect "that our community is made possible by volunteers".
- Questions seeking debugging help without including the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself: does not "make it as easy as possible for others to help", does not respect "that our community is made possible by volunteers".

So, I guess we should now be flagging some (or most) questions closed for those reasons as breaches of the Code of Conduct, so the moderators can apply sanctions against the question askers with the same severity and rapidity sanctions are applied to curators who allow snark into their welcoming comments.

But, rather than requiring manual flagging of those bad questions, why not recognize that closure of a question for one of those reasons (which requires *5 votes* by curators) is *prima facia* evidence of a breach of the Code of Conduct, and automatically raise a moderator flag for those cases, so the question can be rapidly deleted?

Yes, bad questions are *sometimes*, *eventually* deleted. But bad questions that do not meet the expectations of the Code of Conduct should be deleted with the *same* rapidity as snarky comments.

Comment: _"and automatically raise a moderator flag"_ and then what? We already have an automated question ban mechanism...

Comment: Seems rather pointless to make new rulez when questioners already get banned for asking too many poorly received questions.  The CoC doesn't mean squat to those users anyway, it isn't enforceable when they can simply create a new accounts ad-infinitum with a VPN and temporary email accounts.  The CoC was not meant for them, it was meant for you.

Comment: **Comments** of the asker are treated exactly the same as **comments** by others. Questions should be treated exactly the same as answers. I don't understand why you compare questions with comments. I also completely disagree that every unclear or too broad question automatically violates the CoC.

Comment: Questions _are_ already deleted before moderators ever see them.

Comment: I see a new moderator election comming if every question closed for any of those reasons generates a mod flag.

Comment: Even with your edits: Please don't compare actions taken on comments with actions taken on answers/questions.

Comment: Yea, I really don't think a "low quality question" qualifies as a "Code of Conduct violation".

Comment: Not every code of conduct violation is equal. If I start spewing hate, that's different than a remark that might be unfriendly. Low-quality questions are already dealt with in an adequate way imo.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Read the *actual* Code of Conduct: mere snark leads to content deletion, with the potential for repeated violations leading to suspension.

Comment: @Raedwald I've read it. My comment is still true. A difference between snark and posting a low-quality question is intent. Someone posting low-quality content likely doesn't intend to annoy/offend anyone, they just want an answer. For snarky comments, that's different. If there's a solid reason to believe the intent of a low-quality question is malicious, I'd flag it either as rude/abusive or using a custom modflag with explanation..

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You seamless move from snark to malicious intent. Snark is not out-and-out malicious. Snark is not even full-on sarcasm. Friends can be with each other without being malicious.

Comment: @Raedwald: I think you're confusing snark with sarcasm.

Comment: @Raedwald: What I (and I guess others too) are not seeing is the claim you make that all unclear question automatically violating the CoC. I totally agree that questions can violate the CoC (which should be flagged as rude/abusive), but I don't agree that every off-topic question is a violation per-se.

Comment: @BDL Not every comment flagged as rude/abusive *is* rude/abusive. That's why the flag goes to a moderator. Someone going to the trouble of raising a rude/abusive flag is acceptably good evidence that it *is* rude/abusive. 5 trusted site members declaring that a question is "unclear" is good evidence that a question does not meet our expectaions.

Comment: @Raedwald: I guess comments flagged by someone at least offended one person (the flagger), so it's up to mods to decide if they violate the CoC. And from what I saw so far, a large number of them is then really deleted. But it's the opposite for closed questions. Imho, only a very small percentage of closed questions violate the CoC, so whats the point of letting Mods review *all of them*? If you think a question violates the CoC, then flag it. Being closed alone is not a strong evidence for a CoC violation.

Comment: @BDL No, a substantial fraction (possibly even a *majority*) of closed questions violate the Code of Conduct.

Comment: And you can also argue that the CoC violation handling happens implicitly. The close message is the warning, when you continue posting crap, then you get suspended automatically. What else could a moderator do?

Comment: @Raedwald: "No, a substantial fraction (possibly even a majority) of closed questions violate the Code of Conduct": [Citation Needed]?

Comment: @BDL I quoted the relevant part of the CoC in the second paragraph of this post.,

Comment: As I read the CoC, only the points mentioned in "Unacceptable Behavior" would qualify for deletion at all. And even with the sentence you quote I disagree that this means that all (or a large portion of) unclear questions automatically violate the CoC. But I think the discussion here will lead to nowhere, so I'm out.

Answer (score 9):

Demanding that moderators handle all moderation of bad questions personally, rather than allowing the community to handle them, isn't going to increase the amount of deleted questions.  I guarantee you it will decrease the amount.  A **lot**.  There just aren't a lot of moderators, and they can only do so much.  With a site so big, community moderation is simply what it takes to actually moderate bad questions.

As you note, the community already has tools for dealing with these types of questions that violate the CoC.  There are of course more tools that you mentioned.  There are downvotes, close votes, the roomba to delete question (which delete far, far more than moderators do, because it scales so much better), the post rate limiting to discourage people from continuing to ask more, etc.  They simply need to be used more.  Adding a mod flag isn't going to change that.  Now I do feel that the community doesn't use the moderation tools available to it as much as I like; I get the impression you feel the same.  But your proposal isn't going to change that and result in more people trying to moderate bad questions.

There are even some potential changes to better help the community moderate bad questions. 
 If you actually want to see more bad questions actually getting moderated, I'd strongly suggest you consider ways to aid the community members to use the tools already available to them, or improvements to the existing tools to make them more effective.  Trying to move moderation tasks from the community to the mods though will *actively harm* your goals.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR

Part of your feature request are reasonable or already exist, but I think you're interpretation of the frequency of questions violating the CoC is inaccurate.

---

> Autoflag bad closed questions as a breach of the Code of Conduct

Sounds kinda like a spam detector, and this does seem useful.

> it should be easy to flag questions as violations, and bad questions should be deleted just as rapidly as bad comments.

We kinda already have this with spam flags and offensive flags, but updating the Rude/Abusive *question* flag wording might be nice.  Maybe it could use its own "Unfriendly" flag for consistency, but questions and comments are not that similar.  Questions aren't inherently directed at anyone, and they're also community editable.

> Some of the standard close reasons for questions (in whole or in part) indicate failure to meet expectations of the Code of Conduct by a question asker:

Whoa slow down.  There's a clause specifically in the CoC: "Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct **in good faith** may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team" (emphasis preserved).  I don't think the normal kinds of bad questions are "not in good faith" attempts.

> - Unclear what you're asking: does not "make it as easy as possible for others to help"
> - Too broad: for gimme-teh-codez requirements dumps and zero-effort homework questions does not respect "that our community is made possible by volunteers".
> - Questions seeking debugging help without including the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself: does not "make it as easy as possible for others to help", does not respect "that our community is made possible by volunteers".

While this is a failure of SO expectations, this also **does not meet the threshold for Unacceptable Behavior**.  It's not a Put-Down, Personal Attack, Bigotry, and/or Harassment.  The existing mechanisms of questions closure escalating into question bans are sufficient.

> But bad questions that do not meet the expectations of the Code of Conduct should be deleted with the same rapidity as snarky comments.

They already are deleted very quickly.  Spam and profanity detection from chat bots (like the [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) Smoke Detector) escalate these to various chat user who quickly raise enough spam/offensive flags to nuke the post from existence.